# SFTP chroot configuration error

Tags: chroot, sftp

Can anyone see what I have done wrong in this procedure? I can connect to the server as the new user and am in the chrooted directory, but despite setting all the proper root permissions, I cannot add files or directories.

```
sudo mkdir /var/host
sudo groupadd sftp
sudo useradd john -d / -M -N -G sftp -s /bin/false
sudo passwd john

sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Match Group sftp
  ChrootDirectory /var/host
  ForceCommand internal-sftp

service ssh restart
```

Here are the directory permissions

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Jan 24 14:27 host
```

*** UPDATE ***

Ok, I think I understand now. Let me know if this looks good:

```
sudo mkdir /var/sftp
sudo mkdir /var/sftp/host
chown john:sftp /var/sftp/host
sudo groupadd sftp
sudo useradd john -d /var/sftp/host -M -N -G sftp -s /bin/false
sudo passwd john

sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Match Group sftp
  ChrootDirectory /var/sftp/host
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no

sudo service ssh restart
```

Only problem with this solution is that only John can add files and directories i think, or can any member of SFTP?

Answer (score 1):

- I won't make a user with home directory set to `/`.
- `/var/host/` is correctly owned by root and 755 as it is needed for the `chroot` to work. Because it is owned by root of course user `john` can't write to it.
- For user `john` you have to create subdirectories under `/var/host/` for which he has write permission. `john` will never be able to write directly to the chroot (`/var/host/`) as it would be insecure so `sftp` doesn't allow that.

Comment: Hmm but then how do I make the directory appear as root to the user?

Comment: ie if I create /var/sftp/host when John logs in he will be able to back out of host to see all the directories in /var/sftp

Comment: This should just be a single large directory /var/host that lots of users have access to. A large directory for uploading and downloading hosted files.

Comment: @Atomiklan `/var/host/` will appear as `/`. Yes, he will be able to go out to see other directories under `/var/host/` but he will not be able to access those other directories if you don't give him read+execute access on those other dirs. If you just want a single large directory as you say, then use `/var/host/` as `/` just like now, and make only one subdirectory under it. Then the users will only have access to this subdirectory.

Comment: @Atomiklan To say it differently: *"ie if I create /var/sftp/host when John logs in he will be able to back out of host to see all the directories in /var/sftp"* Why make other directories under `/var/sftp/` if you only need one dir?

Comment: I dont want him to be able to back out period. The users should appear to be in / which is /var/host and they should not be able to do any backing out of anywhere. They just need to be able to create directories and file in / (ie /var/host)

Comment: @Atomiklan The `sftp-chroot` does not allow creating diretories/files just under chroot. That is insecure and not allowed. See e.g. [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP-chroot#Write_access_to_chroot_dir)

Comment: That's ok, I think I understand now. See my update above in a minute.

Comment: @Atomiklan That won't work. `chown john:sftp /var/sftp/host` will mean that directory will be not owned by root and `sftp` will not allow you to chroot to that directory. If you chroot to `/var/sftp/` instead it will work. Just to quote again from that page which I linked: "the chroot path **must be owned by root** and **only writable by the owner**." That means only root should be able to write to the chrooted directory.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If its owned by root and only the owner (root) can write to it, how can John? Am I misunderstanding chroot???

Comment: @Atomiklan To the chrooted directory only root can write. John can write to any directory under chroot which you give him permission. But directly to chroot only root should be able to write. This is not a real problem, that is just a *cosmetic* problem that you have to put your directory into a directory. Like putting an envelop in an envelop. Only root can write on the outer envelop, but anyone can write on the inner envelop and anyone can put anything into the inner envelop. Just the outer one has to be kept safe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step guide to allow:

1. SFTP access to /home/bob/uploads (modify as necessary) for user bob
2. Lock bob out of SSH
3. Use username/passwords rather than keys:

First, edit your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd
```

Scroll down and modify:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

and add this at the bottom:

```
Match Group sftpusers
ChrootDirectory %h
ForceCommand internal-sftp
AllowTcpForwarding no
```

Press Ctrl-X to exit and save.

Now add the user:

```
sudo useradd bob
sudo passwd bob
```

Now add the groups and disable ssh:

```
sudo groupadd sftpusers
sudo usermod  -g sftpusers bob
sudo usermod -s /usr/bin/rssh bob
sudo usermod -d /home/bob bob
```

Now set permissions:

```
sudo chown root:root /home/bob/
sudo chmod 755 /home/bob/
sudo mkdir /home/bob/uploads
sudo chown bob /home/bob/uploads

sudo service sshd restart
```

All this is while logged in as a root user (ec2-user on Amazon Linux AMIs)